# Differences JQuery 1.4.2 → 1.4.3 Enough to break good old image gallery †

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, version-control, jquery-plugins

after exaclty six attempts begging the original auhtor of an image popup javascript code to make his script compatible with the newer JQuery libraries, all six in vain, I decided its time for me to fix it without him the seventh attempt, and salvage this otherwise perfectly working (after numerous customisations by me) image popup script.

> Problem: works when JQuery **1.3.2** ~ **1.4.2** is loaded, but NOT when JQuery **1.4.3** ~ **1.5.1** is loaded. On new builds, images don't enlarge after click on the thumbnails, whereas on the old builds, the do!

Any suggesion/help is kindly welcome and appreciated by me highly. Thanks!

## The problem lies somehwere here:

```
//display content
var displayContent = function(img) {
    if (visible) {
        var newImg = jQuery.extend(true, {}, img);
        resizeImg(newImg);

        var imgWidth = newImg.width;
        var imgHeight = newImg.height;
        var outerWidth = imgWidth + hBound;
        var outerHeight = imgHeight + vBound; 

        $lightbox.stop(true).animate({width:imgWidth, height:(imgHeight + cpHeight),
        left: Math.round(($(window).width() - outerWidth)/2),
        top:Math.round(($(window).height() - outerHeight)/2)}, 
        tranSpeed, 
        function() {
            enableCtrl();
            $innerBox.height(imgHeight);
            $info.html(langArrows + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + langImage + " " + (currIndex+1) + "/" + numItems);
            $cpanel.css({top:imgHeight, display:"block"});
            $mainImg.css({width:imgWidth, height:imgHeight})
            .attr("src", newImg.src).animate({opacity:1}, tranSpeed, startTimer);
            showDesc();
        }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Fiddling around with a DOM inspector shows that there is a `display: none` on the `#lightbox` element. When you remove that, you see the image. No idea where exactly it comes from, though

Comment: Have you considered switching to a different lightbox plug-in that does work with jQuery 1.5?

Comment: Wauw Pekka I think you are very close! or as we say in The Netherlands "WAT GOED MAN!" it came from the css styles #lightbox, i removed the `display:none` seems to work only 1 time but causes other problems like doest show the second time you click...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On line 336 add `.show()`  to the end of the chain. While LekisS was on to the right answer, if you add it there, its not properly hidden so the next time you click the image you will see the image display as its thumbnail size for a brief second.

Comment: Thanks @Loktar you Answered my question beyond bauty man! I am very eternally greatfull to these comments! PS nice combination of creative visual designs through code on your website (I like especially your JSLander game I would advise to make this fullscreen since some people have bigger monitors and smaller, why not stretch and allow for full screen real estate usage? another idea would be to add background ambient sounds via .mp3 or much tinier but still cool .mod files... :)

Comment: @Loktar, "Perfect Landing 1396 points" ;-) ... already addicted! make that screen bigger, ps I am architect, and have developed some scenries/buildings/objects for games in the past. would love to help/draw you some scenreies in return and for free.

Comment: Ha nice! I might take you up on that sometime!

Comment: @Loktar: I like your clean code elaborations. PS Couldnt find your email address on your site to send you some of my pure for-gaming-only-scenries-&-artworks in case you might take me on my word some time!  See, as an architect I make distinction during daytime between two sorts of designs A) my concrete designs that can be built and B) my designs that are so awesome/strange/futuristic that just cannot be build yet (funding, safety, regulations, lifestyles etc) and so belong for games only...   Of course these restrictions do not apply during nighttime in dreams: *everything is possible* then.

Comment: @Sam Ah I really need to add my contact info to that site, you can contact me at, me@jasonrb.com